# Single Git push to two remotes with two different Config files?

Tags: git, git-config

I have code that I push to my Bitbucket account regularly. Now, I want to push to two different remotes with single commit, but with different git.config files.
I know that I can setup different remotes like this:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://original/repo.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git://another/repo.git
```

The idea is that one config file I will be setup to include all of my code and another to not include it all. Let say code in folder "A" will be pushed to just one of the remotes. Then I will be able to give an access to the "incomplete" code to someone.

I know that git.config is specific to project, user and system and I am wondering is it possible to setup workflow like this. Is there any way to acompplish that?

Comment: You're likely missing a key concept here: you can define multiple remotes, no need for a hack. Have a look at `git remote add <name> <url>`, then `git push origin master`, `git push anotherremote master`. You can then define default behavior of `git push` without extra arguments to achieve what you want. All of this from within 1 single local repo, same .git/config file.

Comment: @SébastienDawans. How could I define git push for the behaviour I want?

Comment: my comment covers the first part of your question, where you are trying to push to multiple remotes without defining multiple remotes explicitly. As for what you are trying to do wrt. parts of your working tree to different remotes, I would recommend to restructure your project into separate repositories, and have a look at git submodules

Comment: @SébastienDawans. Upvoted. That is brilliant. I just looked at git submodules command. It looks like solution for my problem. I will explore it in detail. Thank you.

Comment: you're welcome, sorry for being too lazy to post an answer. Let's say that doing a bit of searching on your side with the keywords I gave is part of the learning process. Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Git branches (local as well as remote ones) do not work on directories and files but on commits.

Lets name the full source repository `orig` and the stripped repository `pub`. As the history of `pub` isn't allowed to contain changes unique to `orig` the repositories can not simply share the same commit history. Also two bramches (`orig` forking `pub` and adding some stuff e.g.) could be possible but I can't think of any convenient or even usable workflow right now.

It should be possible though to write a small script which utilizes `git filter-branch` to create the `pub` tree from the `orig` repository and push it to the `pub` remote.

As I don't know the exact commands right now from scratch, consider this as a big comment giving a general direction for a possible solution ;)

I'll add some more concrete ideas when I got the commands right.

**Edit 0:** at [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch#_examples) is an example to extract a subdirectory:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter foodir --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

The `--tag-name-filter cat` is used to preserve tags.

You could use this command to either write a script, that clones `orig`, applies the filter and pushes to the `pub` remote everytime you want to.

You could also issue this command once to split up your project into several repositories as [SébastienDawans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875017/single-git-push-to-two-remotes-with-two-different-config-files#comment51671003_31875017) stated.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I am trying to figure out what @Sébastien Dawans recommended

Comment: That is nice feature. I will try it.